# How come my rtl8188cus device cannot connect?

Tags: linux, drivers, wifi

I have a Edimax EW-7811Un usb wifi adapter, which uses a Realtek 8188cus chipset internally. I can use wicd to perform a network scan with the adapter, and it lists the networks correctly. But when I attempt to connect to these networks, it gets to the validating authentication stage then stops, bringing me back to the previous stage of "Not connected". After it fails to connect, I cannot scan again unless I remove the adapter and put it back in.

The device is not faulty, as it works on Windows, it advertises Linux support on the box, and the drivers it uses are the rtl8192cu drivers, which are in the kernel since version 3.0

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at http://www.r-statistics.com/2011/11/edimax-ew-7811un-usb-wireless-connecting-to-a-network-on-ubuntu-11-10/ , there is a solution  for a similar Edimax adapter.